# Image slide not working good when viewpager and imageview in the same xml

Tags: android

I am doing a slide view , and by mistake I have added the pageview and ViewPager in same xml and that caused problems , when I tried to fix it the slide stoped working , so I need help to make the slide working.( In this tutorials [1](http://androidmirchi.com/android-image-slideshow-tutorial-using-viewpager/) and [2](http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/) explained the viewpage should be in another xml but honestly I didnt understand why .

This is SingleViewActivity.java

```
public class SingleViewActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageView image1;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_view);
//
        slide mCustomPagerAdapter = new slide(this);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
}}
```

and this is slide.java

```
public class slide extends PagerAdapter{
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public slide(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.SingleView);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
    public Integer[] mThumbIds =
        { 
                R.drawable.sample2, 
                R.drawable.sample2,
                R.drawable.sample2,
                R.drawable.sample2,
                R.drawable.sample2,
                R.drawable.sample2,
                R.drawable.sample2,
                R.drawable.sample2
         }; 
}
```

Single view.xml

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/SingleView" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@id/edittextm"/>

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

As I understand view pager should be in another xml , please note that I want the images to slide in SingleViewactivity.

Comment: What is not working exactly? Does the app crash when you run it or what? And the `ViewPager` needs to go into the main XML layout for the `Activity`.
The `PagerAdapter`'s items need to have their own XML layout as well, with the `ImageView` inside.

Comment: Yes now its showing an error , but my question about view pager .. it should always exists in main activity xml?  Even if the slide iis on another activity?

Comment: Yes the `ViewPager` should be in the main activity's XML. The different pages in the `ViewPager` should be a separate XML layout.

Comment: @Darwind yes I did solve it you can post as answer and ill accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ViewPager` should be in the main `Activity`'s XML.

The different pages in the `ViewPager` should be a separate XML layout.